# How to fix broken headers in VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

After installing VS2017 and letting it compile my CMake based project it runs into compilation issues in the VS header xlocnum:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocnum
```

Line: 1611:

```
_Bufsize += _CSTD abs(_Ptwo) * 30103L / 100000L;
```

With the error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocnum(1611): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocnum(1599): note: while compiling class template member function '_OutIt std::num_put<wchar_t,_OutIt>::do_put(_OutIt,std::ios_base &,_Elem,long double) const'
          with
          [
              _OutIt=std::ostreambuf_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>,
              _Elem=wchar_t
          ]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocnum(1857): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::num_put<wchar_t,std::ostreambuf_iterator<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocnum(1611): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xlocnum(1611): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Why do you think the definition of `_CSTD` is incorrect? It looks like it should be `::` for c++ files so that you get for example `::abs(_Ptwo)`. What is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: Thats right Alan, I inserted the error output..

Comment: You would not happen to have a macro definition that `#define`s `abs`, would you?

Comment: Good guess, I will parse the code (I'm not the original author).

Comment: If you hover the mouse over `abs` visual studio should show you a hint for any macro definition.